# Why am I getting the error "me is not defined" when redirecting the user?

Tags: templates, authentication, sails.js, boilerplate

I'm getting the error `me is not defined` when a user logs in and is sent to a page using the exit `viewTemplatePath`.

The error occurs in the **header.ejs** template `<% if(me) { %>`, which is the boilerplate for Sails V1.0.

`me`is defined when using a redirect type:

```
exits: {
  success: {
    responseType: 'redirect',
    redirect: '/pages/user-profile',
    description: 'User successfully logged in.'
  }, 
}
```

`me` is not defined when defining a template to render:

```
exits: {
  success: {
    viewTemplatePath: 'pages/user/profile'
    description: 'User successfully logged in.'
  },
}
```

**Sails v1.0 boilerplate**

Comment: We will to see more code... "me is not defined" simply means that the variable "me" have never been defined before being used. Where do you declare the "me" variable ?

Comment: @johnkork - The Sails v1.0 uses "me" in their boilerplate. Yes 'me' is not defined only when redirect is used. https://github.com/balderdashy/seed/blob/master/views/layouts/layout.ejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this problem and none are satisfactory as this problem has a "seemingly" poor consistency. Sometimes `viewTemplatePath` passes `this.req.me` to the template as `me` and sometimes it does not.

**Solution 1:** Pass the user data to the template path

```
return exits.success({me: this.req.me});
```

**Solution 2:** Use the redirect method

**Solution 3:** Check for user before exiting to `viewTemplatePath` and pass me as any value type to not expose user data.

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

  if(!this.req.me) throw {redirect:'/'};

  return exits.success({me: true});

}
```